# Excel 2007 -hyperlinking

Tags: windows-xp

I have lots of document to be hyperlink in excel 2007, the documents/files are located in our server but in different folder base in the company folder structure, how can i hyperlink it?

ling

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Hyperlink" button on the Insert ribbon/menu. Then navigate to the page you want.

For me, it worked to have the form `\\network_computer\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.ext`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just copy and paste the path from the top of the explorer window, and Excel should pick it up as a hyperlink as long as it has the leading backslashes "\".